# KnockoutJS data-bind="Visible :" with two conditions is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

A simple thing I am trying to workout with KnockoutJS.

I have two `dropdowns` and a `textbox`.

**What I need**

If both the dropdowns are selected, then only I should get the checkbox displayed. Otherwise, the text input should not visible.

**What I tried:**

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vikash208/z4x5meua/13/

I used something like this:

```
data-bind="visible: selectedValue && selectedControl"
```

From the above, the conditions are verified as below:

```
IF selectedValue IS TRUE AND selectedControl IS NOT UNDEFINED
```

Kindly provide me a solution and also where I went wrong with it. I am a beginner of `knockoutJS`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use multiple conditions in a binding, you need to unwrap the observables so the entire expression can be evaluated.

To do this, just add brackets after the observable:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: selectedValue() && selectedControl()" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4x5meua/15/)

You could also create another computed observable with your condition in it (note, you still unwrap the observables in the computed observable). This is probably the better option since it keeps the logic in your view model and can be reused.

```
Txt.showCondition = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.selectedItem() && this.selectedValue()
}, this);
```

Then just bind the input to this instead:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: showCondition" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4x5meua/17/)

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle and also especially for your explaination.

Comment: @Vikash I've updated with another option, that's probably better in terms of reusability.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful for me.

Comment: Hi @Steve . I am just trying out with filling the second dropdown values based on first dropdown value chosen. Is it possible ? I tried using the knockoutJS example, but I could not populate the dropdown on edit or pass my JSON as a parameter to bind on "edit details" Is there any way out there ?

Comment: @Vikash you should probably ask a new question with the extra details and the new code you have tried.